# My server is under attack and all my sites go offline randomly

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, wordpress

I have a server with apache on debian 9, recently, all my websites go offline many times every day, when I check apache log:

```
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0921 30985/7fa03ffff700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:422 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0921 30977/7f771ffff700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0921 30985/7fa04a8f8600 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:492 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0921 30977/7f7732eca600 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:901 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0921 30985/7fa03ffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0922 30985/7fa03f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0922 30985/7fa03f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0923 30977/7f76e77fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0923 30977/7f76e77fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0924 30977/7f76e7fff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.8] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0925 30977/7f76e7fff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.8] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0925 30977/7f771f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0925 30977/7f771f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0925 30977/7f771cff9700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0925 30977/7f771cff9700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771ffff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771dffb700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771ffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771dffb700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771d7fa700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771d7fa700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771effd700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771e7fc700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771effd700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30977/7f771e7fc700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.0926 30985/7fa04a8f8600 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1361 31017/7f987925e600 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1447 31020/7fd468370600 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1448 31020/7fd468370600 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1774 31020/7fd468370600 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 31020
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1876 31031/7f6265780600 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1882 31031/7f6265780600 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 31031
[ 2020-04-29 15:57:57.1948 30977/7f7732eca600 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[Wed Apr 29 15:57:57.210403 2020] [:error] [pid 31013] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.5+', found '2.7.13'.
[Wed Apr 29 15:57:57.210465 2020] [:error] [pid 31013] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Wed Apr 29 15:57:57.210469 2020] [:error] [pid 31013] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Wed Apr 29 15:57:57.210483 2020] [:notice] [pid 31013] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Apr 29 15:57:57.210487 2020] [:notice] [pid 31013] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
```

on daemon log I see a lot of this :

```
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 185.136.98.77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 185.136.97.77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 185.136.97.77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 2a06:fb00:1::2:77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 2a06:fb00:1::2:77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 2a06:fb00:1::3:77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 2a06:fb00:1::3:77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 185.136.99.77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 185.136.99.77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 2a06:fb00:1::1:77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 2a06:fb00:1::1:77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 185.136.96.77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 185.136.96.77#53
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: DNS format error from 2a06:fb00:1::4:77#53 resolving www.yarors.top/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#40399: Name . (SOA) not subdomain of zone yarors.top -- invalid response
Apr 29 16:02:14 Server1 named[13933]: FORMERR resolving 'www.yarors.top/AAAA/IN': 2a06:fb00:1::4:77#53
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating com/SOA: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating com/SOA: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating L7DGFU97E1TI7QBM10HCOK1ELAV6M2HT.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating L7DGFU97E1TI7QBM10HCOK1ELAV6M2HT.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating 3RL2Q58205687C8I9KC9MV46DGHCNS45.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:07:30 Server1 named[13933]:   validating 3RL2Q58205687C8I9KC9MV46DGHCNS45.com/NSEC3: no valid signature found
Apr 29 16:09:00 Server1 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Apr 29 16:09:00 Server1 systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
```

How can I identify the source of attack please ? I have multsites on the server and all of theme go offlines randomly many times every day

Thanks

Comment: It's a very unusual Apache log. What is the log file you find this in? And 'received shutdown command'? Something very weird is going on, or you seem to be seriously hacked. Also, do you need to be running your own nameserver? Finally, can you say something about your firewall config and SSH policy / password security?

Comment: For Apache : /var/log/apache2/error.log, for Daemon : /var/log/daemon.log I don't raun my own server, the "ww.yarors.top" isn't mine, I found that this domain is linked to a wordpress attack "WP-VCD", but i dont now how to figure out the source of this on my server , for the firewall, on server I use standard configuration